# Good daughter penalty?

Tags: meaning, phrases

What is the meaning of "good daughter penalty"?

Eg. The impact of "motherhood peanlty" and "good daughter penalty" on gender pay parity is concerning.

Comment: Where have you seen the term being used?

Comment: Seen in an article on gender pay gap. Added the snippet above.

Comment: Did you try searching for the expression?

Comment: Please link to the article or quote a reasonable amount. A quote of a few words isn't exactly context

Comment: A simple Google search for your longer phrase came up with 'The term “motherhood pay penalty” refers to the pay gap between working mothers and similar women without dependent children' in a [document from the British Trades Union Congress](https://www.tuc.org.uk/sites/default/files/MotherhoodPayPenalty.pdf) (PDF)

Answer (score 4):

These appear to be standard terms for describing a couple of factors that affect gender pay parity.

> Women typically earn less than men and are also worse off financially as a result of penalties from career breaks due to taking time away to raise children and care for elderly relatives.
>
> These factors are known as the motherhood penalty and the good daughter penalty.
>
> *[Celebrating the financial power of women](https://www.isjfinancialplanning.co.uk/celebrating-the-financial-power-of-women/)*

The motherhood penalty is probably the more obvious as women are far more likely to take a career break to care for their children than the fathers.

The good daughter penalty is the impact on their careers of the informal caring roles taken on in families for older relatives, which again rarely falls on the men.

Comment: Got it, Thank you :)